# lvscan command not working

Tags: command-line, gparted

I installed fedora 20 with Ubuntu 14.04 and windows 7,then removed it. Now i have dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 and windows 7. In GParted there is a lock. How to remove it. I tried lvscan but it is showing:
`root@gaurav-desktop:/home/gaurav# lvscan
No volume groups found
root@gaurav-desktop:/home/gaurav#`

Second thing fdisk -l is showing something bad i guess and windows 7 in not booting. Purple screen hang while booting in windows 7. Tried boot-repair not working. Pls suggest something.[Command line Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSkP7.png) [Gparted Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRAQL.png)

Answer (score 0):

In GParted a lock icon beside a partition indicates the partition is mounted or otherwise active.

From the screen shot it appears that you are running GParted from the Ubuntu partition (/dev/sda9) on your hard disk.  As such you will not be able to unmount /dev/sda9 because this would be like pulling the carpet out from underneath yourself.

To be able to edit any partition, boot from media other than the hard drive you wish to modify.  For example boot from your Ubuntu Live image and deactivate swap (**Partition -> Swapoff**), or alternatively boot from [GParted Live](http://gparted.org/livecd.php).

Note that the fdisk command line messages are simply indicating that the /dev/sda3 partition is neither cylinder nor MiB aligned, and that the logical partitions were not created in ascending order on the disk.  Your computer will continue to work properly without any action on your part.